# How I can access to the webcamm in cn1 windows desktop build?

Tags: windows, codenameone, desktop

anyone knows how to use my webcam when I capture a photo. I build my app for windows desktop in codenameone. I have a pro account and I need it for a proyect.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop build just uses Java SE which is packaged with the app. Unfortunately JavaSE or JavaFX don't provide webcam access out of the box and the solutions that allow this are pretty complex.

You can use native interfaces which in the JavaSE port just invoke plain Java and try to make use of a project like this: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/

Alternatively, HTML5 does have camera capture builtin so we support this in the JavaScript port see: https://www.codenameone.com/demos-Camera.html